# Global Exception Handling with Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using Spring Cloud Gateway Greenwich.SR1 with Spring Boot 2.1.5. I am trying to create a gateway for my downstream services. Part of the gateway's job is to provide a global error page for downstream requests. When a downstream service returns a HTTP 403 response, I want the gateway to provide a fitting error page.

I am currently using a custom filter like this

```java
public class ForbiddenFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<Object> {

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "Forbidden";
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Object o) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> chain.filter(exchange).then(
                Mono.defer(() -> {
                    if (!exchange.getResponse().isCommitted() &&
                            HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.equals(exchange.getResponse().getStatusCode())) {
                        return Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN));
                    }
                    return Mono.empty();
                }));
    }
}
```

I also have a `403.html` file in `src/main/resources/templates/error/` set up.

The problem is that the gateway returns a 403 response with an empty body instead of the content of the html file. During debugging I can see that `DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler` creates the correct body in form of a `Mono<ServerResponse>` but it is never written the the actual response.

Is there a different way to get this to work?

Comment: maybe because something else already wrote to the response?

Comment: The response ist empty on the client. Mono.error is returned in this filter.

Comment: You are doing this after receiving the response, hence my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem by using a custom `ServerHttpResponseDecorator`. The critial bit of code is to overwrite the `writeWith` method to provide a custom body:

```
ServerHttpResponseDecorator responseDecorator = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(exchange.getResponse()) {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
        if (shouldServeErrorPage(exchange)) {
            exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().setContentLength(-1);
            return errorWebExceptionHandler.handle(exchange, new ResponseStatusException(getHttpStatus(exchange)));
        } else {
            return getDelegate().writeWith(body);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> writeAndFlushWith(
            Publisher<? extends Publisher<? extends DataBuffer>> body) {
        if (shouldServeErrorPage(exchange)) {
            return writeWith(Flux.from(body).flatMapSequential(p -> p));
        } else {
            return getDelegate().writeAndFlushWith(body);
        }
    }

    private boolean shouldServeErrorPage(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        HttpStatus statusCode = getHttpStatus(exchange);
        return statusCode.is5xxServerError() || statusCode.is4xxClientError();
    }
};

return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().response(responseDecorator).build());
```

I have pushed a working sample at https://github.com/tine2k/scg-global-error-page